# How to give all-project access in redmine?

Tags: redmine

Is it possible to create a redmine user, who don't have administrator role, but can view all projects and all issues in the system, including not-public projects?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just add the use to all projects as a member with a role giving them the respective permissions.

All non-admin users follow the permissions applied to them via the roles. Thus, unless a non-admin user is given explicit permissions via a role, they can't see the data. This is one of the basic rules of Redmine's permission system and is required to ensure that permissions apply to normal users.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
But I meant another use case: is there any function to give a user a global role? For example, I want to make user a reporter for all current and future project without giving a role each time when I create a new project.

Comment: No. There are no global roles in Redmine. You have to give the user a role in each project, either manually or via a group.